# Segmentation fault after writing some data into a file

Tags: c, file, io, printf

I am writing a C program which calculates a metric of 94000 image regions and writes the values in a file. I can write the metrics of 51069 regions succesfully, but after that the C program outputs me a segmentation fault. The code is very simple:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  Image *cimg=NULL;
  Image *mask=NULL;
  Image *gt=NULL;
  Image *rmask=NULL;
  Image *nwcimg=NULL;
  Image *nwrmask=NULL;
  Histogram *hist=NULL;
  FILE* output; 

  int x, r, j, y, maxR, minR, index, hsize, value, relevance;
  int min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y;

  //just checking the parameters
  if (argc != 5) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr,"usage: generatemetric<image> <region mask> <ground truth> <feature_file> \n");
      exit(-1);
  }  


    //reading the input image 
    cimg = ReadImage(argv[1]);

    //reading the image segmentation
    mask = ReadImage(argv[2]);

    //reading the ground truth which i will use to label the image regions as +1 and -1
    gt = ReadImage(argv[3]);

    //maximum and minimum region value
    maxR = MaximumValue(mask);
    minR = MinimumValue(mask);

    //i will iterate through all the image regions
    for(r=minR; r <= maxR; r++) 
    {  

            //this is done because I want to know 2 points in the image region
            //to create a bounding box on it
            min_x = mask->ncols-1;
            min_y = mask->nrows-1;
            max_x = 0;
            max_y = 0;


            for(y=0; y < mask->nrows; y++) 
            {
                 for(x=0; x < mask->ncols;x++)
                 {  
                    index = y*(mask->ncols)+x;

                    if(mask->val[index] == r) 
                    {
                          if(x < min_x)
                          min_x = x;
                          if(y < min_y)
                          min_y = y;
                          if(x > max_x)
                          max_x = x;
                          if(y > max_y)
                          max_y = y;
                     }
                   }
                 }

        nwcimg = CreateImage(max_x-min_x,max_y-min_y);
        nwrmask = CreateImage(max_x-min_x,max_y-min_y);

        //creating ROIS
        CreateROI(cimg, nwcimg, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y);
        CreateROI(mask, nwrmask, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y);                
        //calculating region class
        relevance = isRelevant(gt, mask, r);

        //makes the region of interest white in the bounding box
        make_binary(nwrmask,r);

      //calculates the metric only in the bounding box around the region of interest (a vector that is a kind of histogram)
        hist=metric(nwcimg,nwrmask);

       //starting to write

       //histogram size
       hsize = hist->n;

      //open the file to append the values
      //the problem starts here after 51069 iterations
      output = fopen(argv[4], "a+");

      //record the region class in the file         
      fprintf(output, "%d, ", relevance);

      //record each value of the histogram as comma separated values
      for(j = 0; j < hsize; j++) 
      {
            value = hist->v[j];
            fprintf(output, "%d, ", value);
      }
      //recod the region id
      fprintf(output,"%d \n", r+1);
      fclose(output);
  DestroyHistogram(&hist);
  DestroyImage(&nwcimg);
  DestroyImage(&nwrmask);

}
DestroyImage(&rmask);
DestroyImage(&gt);
DestroyImage(&cimg);
DestroyImage(&mask);
return(0);
}
```

in other words, at each of the 94000 iterations, the program opens the file, write values and close it. I think maybe i'm having a lot of I/O when the program runs. Am I right? or it's other kind of problem? anybody here faced this problem before? how to solve it?

Comment: Run the program in a debugger, this way you are told **where** the program crashed.

Comment: Sound like you're leaking memory, maybe in the `metric` function.  Either show us this code and/or run a debugger on it.

Comment: The code you posted seems ok, but you should check the retrn value of the file operatons. I would look in the `metric` function. Maybe you have a memory leak there and you get the segmentation fault after a failed `malloc`?

Comment: Look to your array and pointer accesses. Array subscript out of bounds or invalid pointers are the most likely reasons. And to second what alk said, run your program under a debugger. And if you don't know how to use your debugger then now is the time to learn.

Comment: It's completely impossible to say for sure what the problem may be, as we have no idea of the size of `relevance` or range of `r`, whether `hist->v` is big enough to cope with `v[j]` in all cases, etc, etc. Most likely, the problem isn't completely in the code you have posted (not unusual!)

Comment: when I debug the program from the point it stops there is no problem. So, the problem is the leak of memory?

Comment: It's possible that your `metric` function has a bug that causes it to write outside of its allocated memory, corrupting the heap and causing functions such as `malloc` and `fopen` to malfunction. It is also unclear why you call `fopen` in append mode in every iteration of the loop - can't you do that once?

Comment: @MatsPetersson the range of r is [0,94000], relevance is -1 or +1 and hist->size is always 32

Comment: @user4815162342 i can do the fopen outside the loop without problems. Can this solve my problem?

Comment: @mad It will not solve the problem (but it might hide it, which is arguably even worse), the inefficiency of repeated `fopen` was just a remark on the side.

Comment: Well, clearly SOMETHING is wrong. You need to either supply enough source code to make an standalone example that can be compiled (contains all the required source code to compile, has a `main`, and relevant input/output data) [note this doesn't mean you should post > 1000 lines of code for us to debug your problem]. Or you will have to debug your code. There's nothing obviously wrong in the code you have posted, but there are lots of possibilities of things being wrong in some OTHER code.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I updated the source code in the question. Thanks

Comment: Still not able to compile your source, as we have no idea what `CreateImage`, `CreateROI` and other functions actually do.

Comment: I'm sure it's MUCH faster to run your code in a debugger than asking here for someone else to debug your code. It's a skill you will need to be able to do programming anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that this `mask->val[index]` operation is not going out of bound?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I am debugging the source code. I will post the error after the debug stops. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by fopening the file out of the loop and fclosing after the loop as suggested by user4815162342. I think the problem was lots of i/o and also there were some concurrent processes in my college's cluster. The program finished running right now. Thank you all for your attention and help.